# Сортировка методов в коде

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Имеет ли Visual Studio средства с помощью которых можно было бы выполнить сортировку методов в коде? Например, по алфавиту, по доступу и т п?

Если нет, то какие есть решения?

Comment: Панель Class View. В Settings можно выбрать, что показывать. В нижней панели можно включить нужную сортировку.

Comment: А исходный код так же отсортируется?

Comment: Нет, это только в панели сортировка.

Comment: [How can i sort fields, properties, methods in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3326322/2881286)

Comment: Хм, а зачем? Надо сортировать методы от высокоуровневых к низкоуровневых, автоматика с этим никакая не справится

Comment: Такое можно через ReSharper [сделать](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/File_and_Type_Layout.html). Стандартно в этом плане студия не очень богата как по мне...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Поделюсь своим опытом по автоматическому форматированию C# кода без использования ReSharper-а. 
 Уже долгое время использую расширение [CodeMaid](http://www.codemaid.net) для чистки кода. Расширение умеет:

- форматировать код
- удалять пустые строки
- сортировать пространства имен
- добавлять пропущенные модификаторы доступа
  и другое.

В том числе это расширение умеет и выполнять сортировку элементов класса документа по алфавиту(функция называется **Code Reorganizing**). 
Расширение имеет **два критерия** сортировки:

- тип элемента
- уровень доступа элемента

Вот так выглядит основная его страница с настройками сортировки[image: Основная страница с настройками]

Как видим, мы можем выбрать порядок критериев сортировки(что главнее, *тип элемента*, или *доступ*). 
 Каждый критерий имеет дополнительные  настройки: 
 1. **Критерий уровень доступа** на этой же странице имеется переключатель для настройки порядка сортировки(от public к private или наоборот). 
 2. **Критерий тип элемента** настраивается на отдельной странице, где можно выбрать порядок расположения элементов. Например, можно настроить такой порядок: сначала идут конструктор(ы), потом поля класса, потом свойства, потом методы и так далее)[image: Окно настройки]
Внутри группы элементы будут сортироваться по алфавиту! Обратный порядок сортировки у меня не работает! 
  Также типы элементов можно объединять в одну группу, чтобы внутри группы элементы имели равный приоритет и сортировались по алфавиту. Для примера, в приведенной настройке выше указано, что конструктор и поля класса должны сортироваться по алфавиту в одной группе(пример не совсем удачный, но это пример). Соответственно, конструктор класса будет отсортировать куда-то "в середину" полей класса.
Вызвать сортировку элементов вы можете через главное меню в VS или через контекстное меню редактора. Пункт меню для текущей версии расширения называется 
*Reorganize active document*

Таким образом, расширение CodeMaid  позволяет выполнять сортировку элементов класса исходного кода для C#. Ну и кроме того, расширение будет полезно для использования других возможностей по чистке C# кода.

Answer (score 2):

[CodeFormatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-599079.CodeFormatter)

Features:

- Format the class file (.cs) to arrange members of class in the proper order.
- ...

Answer (score 0):

Незнаю, поможет ли, но на языке **Python** можно написать програмку сортировки методов в коде (если не устраивают существующие), т.к. на Python'е есть все необходимое для работы с файлами. Есть подходяший режим для чтения и записи, так что  в принципе это тоже вариант. Кстати, на **С#** есть тоже что-то подобное. Таким образом можно сделать сортировку под свой вкус, если есть время и силы писать код. После написания программы потребуется лишь менять имя файла с кодом и запускать.

Comment: Вы это на полном серьезе? Осилите на Питоне парсер языка?

Comment: Я не говорю что я сам смогу. Я просто предлагаю автору вопроса такое решение. Хоть это и трудный путь, но тоже вариант. Все зависит от самого автора. Захочет, сможет -- напишет, не захочет / не сможет -- не напишет. Мое дело предложить)